# SQL Table Transformation Course on Code Academy

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

This question is from the `SQL` table transformation course from Code Academy. I am curious to know the difference between the following 2 queries and why the result set showed different answers:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `airports.code` may have duplicates.  In this case, joining from the `flights` to `airports` table could result in duplicated rows, as a record from `flights` could match multiple records in `airports`.

If the field `airports.code` were distinct, i.e. there were no duplicates in that column, then both queries would have returned the same number of results.  Consider the following sample data:

flights:

```
origin
1
2
3
```

airports:

```
code
1
1
2
3
```

It should be clear that the `WHERE IN` query (the first one) would return only three records, one for each `origin` value.  But the second query with the join would actually return *four* records, since `origin=1` would match *twice* to `code=1`.